# TCP with different programming languages

Tags: java, networking

I've a doubt in java socket programming. The tcp server is created Java Socket Programming and running in different machine. Now I want to create a client for the server to request some data from server. Am I need to use same Java socket programming or I can use different APIs to communicate with server and get response back?

Thanks,
Pramod

Answer (score 2):

If the server is using sockets, then yes, the client should also be written using the sockets API. This can be done in any programming language, not necessarily Java.

To give you a broader perspective, there exist other technologies that allow two processes to communicate ([RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html), [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) etc). However, it is almost always the case that both sides of the communication have to use the same technology to be able to talk to each other.

Comment: Hi thanks, The server is written using Java Networking API. So my client also should written using Java Networking API or I can use different APIs to communicate with server? Why i am asking this question because there are some other applications which are developed in different technologies communicating with same server. They can acheive the connection and get response from the server.

Comment: The client can be written in any language using whatever sockets API it provides. Your second paragraph is a complete irrelevance.

Comment: Oh! got it thanks. Can I ask you one more question? How can I create a server which should always listen to a specified port? When ever there is a request from client should respond to client.

Comment: @Pramo: I'd recommend starting with this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Can I use JMS/ESB to acheive this?

Comment: @Pramo JMS is an API to a number of external products. Did you mean EJB?

Comment: Not EJB, Enterprise Service Bus one of my team member suggested to use ESB for TCP/IP messaging but I am not sure how to use ESB for TCP/IP messages. Because ESB is mainly designed for EAI.

Answer (score 2):

You must also use sockets, but not necesserily in Java. Virtually any programming language can talk to different machines based on TCP/IP or UDP sockets. You can even use tools like [`nc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) to test your server.